# Zenity alternative for Bash scripts in package sources?

Tags: bash, zenity

[Zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) is a bit too limited for my use cases. What are the alternatives?

It must be inside package sources, and it must be useable from within Bash scripts.

Answer (score 2):

[Yad](https://code.google.com/p/yad/) (yet another dialog) is a fork of Zenity with many improvements, such as custom buttons, additional dialogs, pop-up menu in notification icon and more.

You can install yad using the following PPA,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install yad
```

See [example demonstrations](https://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples) how to use yad in shell scripts.

Comment: It's not in ubuntu package sources.

Comment: As James says it's not in the package sources but it is available using PPA. I came across this question but had to look elsewhere to find out about yad, so to save anyone else the bother:  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager`   `sudo apt-get update`   `sudo apt-get install yad`   There are examples here:  <https://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples>

Comment: Link here:  [link](https://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/Examples)

Comment: Previous comments suggest Yad is not in the default Ubuntu package repositories; but as of August 2023, it is in the most recent LTS (Jammy, 22.04 - https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/utils/yad), and I believe has been in the default repos since about Xenial (16.04).